# Views overlapping app compat support action bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-view, android-appcompat

I was letting a friend test my app, but he noticed some strange issues with the layout. All of the views in listview would hover onto of the action bar.
The thing is, I'm unable to reproduce this on my own devices or emulators, so I'm assuming it's specific to certain versions of Android? Does anyone know the issue here
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.brainicism.summonertracker.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/trackingList"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

[image: Text overlaying actionbar]

[image: Buttons overlaying actionbar]

Comment: add full code of both file content_main & activity_main

Comment: added full code of both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed the issue using the following attribute in my content_main.xml

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```